# Android Studio hangs when gradle build fails

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio was working fine till this evening until I copies the GridLayout code from internet but forgot to update the dimen resource folder according to it and click on build gradle. First gradle build fails and then android studio freezes. I tries to restart it so many times but the same problem remains.Android studio is working fine for other projects but for freezes evertime i open this project.

I know this problem had been asked so many times and I had tries all the given methods given there but none of them works for me. Any one else having the same issue and if yes how did you solve this?

My Android Studio version is 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar problem. hopefully, i get rid of this problem using this solution. it can help you
 [performance improvement of android stuio](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

On the bottom of android studio where gradle is in processing there is a little red cross you can cancel syncing gradle with that.and if android studio not opened yet you can cancel that with the gradle dialog then you can fix the problem then sync again

Comment: Isn't its a temporary solution as everytime i have to stop the gradle and then make changes?

Comment: when you fix the problem then wont hang next time!!